# How to use returning value in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.6.

I want to use returning value at the same query, but later, something like this:

```
WITH new_track AS 
(
    INSERT INTO eco.tracks (id, first_time, last_time) 
    VALUES ('71C055', '2018/04/10', '2018/04/10') 
    RETURNING track
) 
SELECT * 
FROM eco.new_tracks 
WHERE track = (SELECT track FROM new_track);
```

Is it possible?

I have now tried:

```
WITH new_track AS 
(
    INSERT INTO eco.tracks (id, first_time, last_time) 
    VALUES ('71C055', '2018/04/10', '2018/04/10') 
    RETURNING *
) 
SELECT * 
FROM eco.new_tracks 
WHERE track = (SELECT track FROM new_track);
```

This is not working

Comment: What exactly does "is not working" mean? Do you get an error? Or an empty result set? And how exactly do you want to "use" the newly inserted values? It seems you are inserting into one table (`tracks`) and then selecting from a second table (`new_tracks`). If that `track` column is a sequence/serial column, how do you expect the ids to be in the 2nd table?

Comment: *"This is not working"* is not a useful description of what seems to go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mentioned example, the `SELECT` has to retrieve the whole row just inserted, so an `INSERT... RETURNING *` is more appropriate.

In general, it's not possible in a `WITH` construct to read up-to-date values for the rows that another part of the query writes into. This is documented in [`WITH` Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other
>   and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
>   happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same
>   snapshot (see Chapter 13), so **they cannot “see” one another's effects
>   on the target tables**. This alleviates the effects of the
>   unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that
>   RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between
>   different WITH sub-statements and the main query

Comment: I got it, can you look at upd version? It's not working

Comment: @NikKonst: you're inserting into table 1 and reading from table 2. What do you expect and why?

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

If track is a serial column it might be easier to use `lastval`.

See [Sequence Manipulation Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) in the PostgreSQL documentation.

On the other hand, your example seems to be functionally equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO eco.tracks (id, first_time, last_time)
VALUES ('71C055', '2018/04/10', '2018/04/10') 
RETURNING *
```